# On hover, change color and back

Tags: jquery, css

I have a button that I'm trying to create, where when someone hovers over it, I want the following action to occur -->

While hovering
1)The color fades into a different one
2)The different color fades back into the first color

The trick is though that I want the fading back to happen during the hover state, not when the user mouses away from the button.

The second trick is that I in order to achieve the shape, I have quite a few border manipulations, and I'd like them to change accordingly as well.

Here's a jsfiddle of the button --> http://jsfiddle.net/88B3e/1/

The HTML -->

```
<a href="#" class="more">
  <span class="triangle1"></span>
  <span class="thoughts">thoughts?</span><span class="triangle"></span>
</a>
```

The CSS -->

```
.triangle1 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0%;
  width: 0px;
  border-top: 12px solid #de8063;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #de8063;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: 12px solid #f5f3f0;
}
.thoughts {
  float: left;
  background-color: #de8063;
  padding: 3px 2px 2px 4px;
  color: #f0dfd8;
  font-family: 'PT Sans';
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.triangle {
  float: left;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0%;
  width: 0px;
  border-top: 12px solid #f5f3f0;
  border-left: 12px solid #de8063;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #f5f3f0;
}
```

Your sage advice is sorely needed :).

Cheers,
Stepan

Comment: **The trick is though that I want the fading back to happen during the hover state, not when the user mouses away from the button.** I didnt get this statement, do you want to call mouse in and mouse out manually?

Comment: Hey Dreamweiver, thanks for taking the time to read this!

What I mean is that when a person is hovering over the element, during this span of time, I'd like for a different color to fade in, and than fade out. 

Normally, it will only fade out once the person moves the mouse away :).

Comment: Use the .mouseover event. Then have it fade in over x amount of time and then fade out. What color do you want the button to become?

Comment: Hey Kramer, I see, thanks! Do you have a good resource on using it? The color would be #bc9c00

Comment: @StepanParunashvili:is this what you wanted ? http://jsfiddle.net/88B3e/1/

Comment: Hey @dreamweiver, I don't seem to see a change, can you elaborate on what you changed?

Comment: @StepanParunashvili: oh sorry i forgot to update my jsfiddle :) . here`s the updated link http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/88B3e/4/

Comment: Yeah, I was about to say the same. Anyway, I tried changing the backgound using the .animate function, but that doesn't work for background color, it works for opacity, so if these were divs I could have another div fade in behind it, but it's a span, so it won't work that way...

Comment: Also no, that's not what he wanted. I know what he wants, but it's harder than I first thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I do this with jquery and css3

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.more').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('moreHover');  
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('a.more').removeClass('moreHover');}, 3000);
    });

});
```

[working File](http://jsfiddle.net/88B3e/5/)

Comment: Thanks Sonasish! This works great. Mark, Dreamweiver, Ryan, thanks so much for pushing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.thoughts:hover{
    color:#bc9c00;
    transition:.85s;
}
```

and it will work propperly.

If you want to let the color chance back while you are hovering, you need to get some mouseover event.
I am not really common with this so can't help you with that though!

Comment: I do have to say that the color you have chosen is not really readable, go for a way lighter color or darker color. Something like this?: FFcfba51